# Why is the PersistentConnection (SignalR) instantiated twice for every client?

Tags: signalr

I use a PersistentConnection
Make a route for connection:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<MyConnection>("echo", "echo/{*operation}");
}
```

Why is `MyConnection(PersistentConnection)` called twice every time a client is connecting?

Comment: That's not enough code to make sense of what you're asking. Can you provide a full sample and explain what is getting called twice and also what verison of SignalR you are using?

Comment: I used this example:[link](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections).Version:0.5.2

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the client makes two requests to the server, when establishing the connection:

- a ***negotiate***-request
  this is when the client and server exchange the supported/preferred transports (e.g. 'webSockets', 'longPolling') and determine which one to use
- the real ***connect***-request

A new instance of your `MyConnection` class is created for each incoming request. That's why the constructor is called twice.